# Rebuilding existing app with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Do I have to rebuild my existing apps with the Swift language in order to support iOS8 when it will be released and the most of iPhone owners upgrade to this version? If I must rebuild my apps to new standards or not? At moment my apps are running under iOS6.

My main concern is if I have to abandon the iOS6 version or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I watched the announcement, but [here's a blog](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/06/02/apple-adds-new-iosos-x-programming-language-swift/)  to support me :

> Matter of fact, Swift code can co-exist with Objective-C...
>       Developers don’t need to choose between C for Mac development and Objective-C for iOS     development because Swift supports both iOS and OS X and can co-exist with C and Objective-C code.

For the time being, Apple plans to support both Swift, Objective-C, and hybrid apps built with both.

No, you do not need to abandon iOS 6 .. although with 89% of devices running iOS 7, you may considering doing it soon ...

Comment: also in iOS6 environment? Guess not!

Comment: No, you do not need to abandon iOS 6 .. although with 89% of devices running iOS 7, you may considering doing it soon ...

Answer (score 2):

No, you will not need to rebuild your apps with Swift. The compiler compiles Objective C and Swift down to the same code to run on your iPhone and both languages can co-exist. Objective C will likely be phased out gradually over a number of years.

If you still wish to switch your existing apps over to Swift, [here's a handy migration guide from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html).